# Vagrant : An AMI must be configured via "ami" (region: #{region})

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, vagrant

I got an error as below when run vagrant command,

```
 # vagrant up --provider=aws
```

There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

**AWS Provider:
* An AMI must be configured via "ami" (region: #{region})**

I'm using Vagrant 2.0.1 with vagrant-aws 0.7.2

**Vagrant file:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    require 'vagrant-aws'
    Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
        config.vm.box = 'Vagarent'
        config.vm.provider 'aws' do |aws, override|
        aws.access_key_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        aws.secret_access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        aws.keypair_name = 'ssh-keypair-name'
        aws.instance_type = "t2.micro"
        aws.region = 'us-west-2a'
        aws.ami = 'ami-1122298f0'
        aws.security_groups = ['default']
        override.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'
        override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/ssh-keypair-file'
      end
    end
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`us-west-2a` is not a valid region name, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region for the full list of available region and end-points.

If you AMI is location in US West (Oregon), then you need to replace with `us-west-2` in your Vagrantfile

Comment: Frédéric Henri - Thanks. Yes. I changed to  aws.region = 'us-west-2' instead of     aws.region = 'us-west-2a', still I'm getting same error. Can you please assess any other possibilities  ?

Answer (score 1):

Going through "vagrant-aws" [documentation](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws#configuration), following worked for me.

Installed "vagrant-aws" plugin with shell:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

Added AWS compatible 'dummy-box' named "aws" added in `config.vm.box = "aws"`:

```
vagrant box add aws https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box
```

Created following Vagrant file:

```
# Require the AWS provider plugin
require 'vagrant-aws'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "aws"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"      

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
     aws.access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
     aws.secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']
     aws.region = "us-east-1"
     #aws.availability_zone = "us-east-1c"

     # EC2 Instance AMI
     aws.ami =  "ami-aa2ea6d0" # Ubuntu 16.04 in US-EAST
     aws.keypair_name = "awswindows" #change as per your key
     aws.instance_type = "t2.micro"
     aws.block_device_mapping = [{ 'DeviceName' => '/dev/sda1', 'Ebs.VolumeSize' => 10 }]
     aws.security_groups = ["YOUR_SG"]
     aws.tags = {
        'Name' => 'Vagrant EC2 Instance'
        }  
    # Credentials to login to EC2 Instance
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = ENV['AWS_PRIVATE_KEY']
  end  

end
```

Fired `vagrant up --provider=aws`.

Check once and let me know if you face any issue.